# How to nest methods in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

This is a pretty basic question however, I struggled to find any answers online.

I know that we can nest functions, however I wanted to see if we could do the same with methods in classes

Consider the example below:

```
class name:
     def name(self):
            def name2(self):
                print("Hello world!")
             return self.name2()
    
 m = name()
 m.name()
```

Whenever I run the following code I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'name' object has no attribute 'name2'
```

I would highly appreciate it if someone could help me find a solution.

Comment: If you just want to call `self.name2()` inside name method, you don't need to nest them. Just create 2 separate methods and call them exactly like this

Comment: This looks like it might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/395122), please tell us what problem you are trying to solve, instead of showing your attempted solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code makes no sense. `name2` is just a local variable of the `name` method, and a regular function.

```py
class name:
     def name(self):
         def name2():
             print("Hello world!")
         return name2()
    
 m = name()
 m.name()
```

there, that works.

Python methods are function attributes *of class objects*, they're not special or especially magical, but they certainly can't be *defined* as locals.

I have no idea what you're trying to achieve or what your mental model of the entire thing is, but I'm not sure either makes any sense.

Comment: Thank for answering, I guess I got a bit confused. 

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the way python classes work. If you've defined a standalone function inside a method, the function doesn't automatically become a member of a class.

Rather you've defined a function just like any other function with the addition of a [scope](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html). The scope limits the visibility of the function within the method `name()`.

I think [this](https://www.codesdope.com/blog/article/nested-function-scope-of-variable-closures-in-pyth/) sums of your query and more.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me understand it a lot more!